# glog doesn't compile on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, gflags, glog

I tried to install "glog" but when I hit "make" the compilation fails with the following Error message:

> src/logging_unittest.cc:1206:1: error: ‘FlagSaver’ was not declared in
>   this scope src/logging_unittest.cc:1206:1: note: suggested
>   alternative: /usr/local/include/gflags/gflags.h:277:23: note:
>   ‘gflags::FlagSaver’ src/logging_unittest.cc:1206:1: error: expected
>   ‘;’ before ‘fs’ make: *** [logging_unittest-logging_unittest.o] Error
>   1

I already installed gflags, but apparantly it is not able to find the functions installed along with gflags. Do I need to adapt my LD_LIBRARY_PATH ?

(I already tried to compile gflags from source with the option "-DGFLAGS_NAMESPACE=google" but it didn't help)

Comment: What steps will reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 3):

After hours I could finally solve the problem. I used this version of gflags

```
wget https://github.com/schuhschuh/gflags/archive/master.zip
```

and compiled it using

```
unzip master.zip
cd gflags-master
mkdir build && cd build
export CXXFLAGS="-fPIC"
cmake .. -DGFLAGS_NAMESPACE=google
make 
sudo make install
```